# IdentityServer3 Token Not Getting Deleted on Logout

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, logout, identityserver3

I am using IdentityServer3 and have implemented a custom grant flow for backwards compatibility with an existing SSO implementation.  I am using reference tokens for API authentication.  I have implemented ITokenHandleStore and also IUserService.

I am able to log in successfully and access my application.  The issue is that after I logout, the reference token is still valid.

Upon logout I call HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut();  I also make a call to /connect/endsession?id_token_hint=mYrEfErEnCeToKeN and pass the reference token for the user on the query string parameter.

However, neither the SignOutAsync method in IUserService nor the RemoveAsync method in ITokenHandleStore ever gets called.  Because of this, the token remains in my Token Database table and gets treated like a valid token on subsequent requests even after the user has been logged out.

What is the proper way of logging out a user when doing a Custom Grant flow? How do I get the record deleted out of my database token store?

When I call the endsession endpoint the logging from IdentityServer displays this:

> Sam.Web.MicroServices.IdentityService.vshost.exe Information: 0 :
>   2016-07-13 04:07:14.835 -04:00 [Information] End access token
>   validation request Sam.Web.MicroServices.IdentityService.vshost.exe
>   Information: 0 : 2016-07-13 04:09:22.289 -04:00 [Information] Start
>   end session request Sam.Web.MicroServices.IdentityService.vshost.exe
>   Information: 0 : 2016-07-13 04:09:22.349 -04:00 [Information] Start
>   end session request validation
>   Sam.Web.MicroServices.IdentityService.vshost.exe Information: 0 :
>   2016-07-13 04:09:22.412 -04:00 [Information] Start identity token
>   validation Sam.Web.MicroServices.IdentityService.vshost.exe Error: 0 :
>   2016-07-13 04:09:22.581 -04:00 [Error] Malformed JWT token
>   System.ArgumentException: IDX10709: 'jwtEncodedString' is not well
>   formed: '7dc2417fb752d096af2870c46ca8a181'. The string needs to be in
>   compact JSON format, which is of the form:
>   '..'.    at
>   System.IdentityModel.Tokens.JwtSecurityToken..ctor(String
>   jwtEncodedString) in
>   c:\workspace\WilsonForDotNet45Release\src\System.IdentityModel.To
>   kens.Jwt\JwtSecurityToken.cs:line 68    at
>   IdentityServer3.Core.Validation.TokenValidator.GetClientIdFromJwt(String
>   token) in
>   c:\local\identity\server3\Core\source\Core\Validation\TokenVa
>   lidator.cs:line 347 Sam.Web.MicroServices.IdentityService.vshost.exe
>   Error: 0 : 2016-07-13 04:09:22.648 -04:00 [Error] No clientId
>   supplied, can't find id in identity tok en.
>   Sam.Web.MicroServices.IdentityService.vshost.exe Error: 0 : 2016-07-13
>   04:09:22.701 -04:00 [Error] "Error validating id token hint." "{
>   \"SubjectId\": \"unknown\",   \"Raw\": {
>       \"id_token_hint\": \"7dc2417fb752d096af2870c46ca8a181\"   } }" Sam.Web.MicroServices.IdentityService.vshost.exe Information: 0 :
>   2016-07-13 04:09:22.753 -04:00 [Information] Redirecting to logout
>   page Sam.Web.MicroServices.IdentityService.vshost.exe Information: 0 :
>   2016-07-13 04:09:22.872 -04:00 [Information] Logout endpoint submitted
>   Sam.Web.MicroServices.IdentityService.vshost.exe Information: 0 :
>   2016-07-13 04:09:22.944 -04:00 [Information] Clearing cookies
>   Sam.Web.MicroServices.IdentityService.vshost.exe Information: 0 :
>   2016-07-13 04:09:23.013 -04:00 [Information] rendering logged out page

When I make a call to the /revocation endpoint the IdentityServer logs displays this:

> Sam.Web.MicroServices.IdentityService.vshost.exe Information: 0 :
>   2016-07-13 04:11:14.822 -04:00 [Information] CORS request made for
>   path: "/connect/r evocation" from origin:
>   "chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop"
>   Sam.Web.MicroServices.IdentityService.vshost.exe Information: 0 :
>   2016-07-13 04:11:14.864 -04:00 [Information] AllowedOrigins configured
>   and origin "c hrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop" is
>   not allowed Sam.Web.MicroServices.IdentityService.vshost.exe
>   Information: 0 : 2016-07-13 04:11:14.906 -04:00 [Information] Exiting;
>   origin "chrome-extension://fhb jgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop" is not
>   allowed Sam.Web.MicroServices.IdentityService.vshost.exe Information:
>   0 : 2016-07-13 04:11:14.941 -04:00 [Information] CorsPolicyService did
>   not allow origin Sam.Web.MicroServices.IdentityService.vshost.exe
>   Information: 0 : 2016-07-13 04:11:15.005 -04:00 [Information] Start
>   token revocation request 2016-07-13 04:11:15.063 -04:00 [Debug] Start
>   client validation 2016-07-13 04:11:15.064 -04:00 [Debug] Start parsing
>   for X.509 certificate 2016-07-13 04:11:15.065 -04:00 [Debug] client_id
>   is not found in post body 2016-07-13 04:11:15.066 -04:00 [Debug] Start
>   parsing for secret in post body 2016-07-13 04:11:15.067 -04:00 [Debug]
>   No secret in post body found 2016-07-13 04:11:15.068 -04:00 [Debug]
>   Start parsing Basic Authentication secret
>   Sam.Web.MicroServices.IdentityService.vshost.exe Information: 0 :
>   2016-07-13 04:11:15.069 -04:00 [Information] Parser found no secret
>   Sam.Web.MicroServices.IdentityService.vshost.exe Information: 0 :
>   2016-07-13 04:11:15.124 -04:00 [Information] No client secret found
>   Sam.Web.MicroServices.IdentityService.vshost.exe Information: 0 :
>   2016-07-13 04:11:15.175 -04:00 [Information] Returning error:
>   invalid_client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are receiving an error on logout is because you are passing back an access token in the `id_token_hint` parameter. This parameter requires the identity token that was issued to you upon log in (assuming you are using OpenID Connect).

If you are only using OAuth, then the endsession endpoint is not for you. Instead to revoke the access token you need to use the [revocation endpoint](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/endpoints/revocation.html). This will then delete the token from your database.

The error you are receiving from the revocation endpoint seems to be related to a different issue (looks like you aren't supplying a client id and secret).

Comment: I will test this out today and assuming it works I will accept this answer. Thanks!